Managing amount of DB connections of QgsDataSourceUri with PyQGIS
So basically I have a simple code that adds vector layers to the QGIS project from PostgreSQL.
self.uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
self.uri.setConnection(
    self.host,
    self.port,
    self.db,
    self.user,
    self.passwd,
)

self.uri.setDataSource(
    aSchema='some_schema',
    aTable='some_table',
    aGeometryColumn='geom',
    aSql='',
    aKeyColumn='id',
)
self.some_layer = QgsVectorLayer(
    self.uri.uri(),
    'some_name',
    'postgres',
)
self.some_layer.triggerRepaint()
self.project.addMapLayer(self.some_layer)

but the problem is that each layer creates a connection to the database, and if there are 10 layers, then there will be 10 constant connections at the same time.
How can we reduce the number of connections?

You can connect through pgpool instead of directly. It'll accept the connection from each layer and route its queries through the same few actual connections you configure it to open on the db. Client libraries usually also come with a pool, so you can use that instead of setting up a separate thing and I think QGIS already offers and normally defaults to using a built-in pool.
